# How do I see the SQL that ponyorm generates?

Tags: python, ponyorm

In this example:

```
with db_session:
    p = select(_ for _ in Person in _.name == 'John')[:][0]
```

I need this for debugging purposes, since I would like to see the SQL it generates to a similar query in other ORMs.

Comment: Instead of `[:][0]` it will be more efficient to use `.first()` method. This way Pony will add `LIMIT 1` to the query and don't retrieve unnecessary data from the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can use `pony.orm.sql_debug(True)`. This will show you all the SQL that pony generates whenever one is in a transaction. [Debugging SQL in Pony](https://docs.ponyorm.org/firststeps.html#using-the-debug-mode)